# iOS 8 swift Framework link agains 3rd party objective c framework

Tags: swift, xcode6

I'm building my own Swift framework `MyAppKit` so I've created a separate XCode target for this. In this framework, I need to use a 3rd party Objective C `Parse.framework`. If I include the `Parse.h` in the Objective-C Bridging header if my framework, I get the error

```
using bridging headers with framework targets is unsupported
```

Is this a bug or is it really not supported ? If it's the case, shall I just include all the `MyAppKit` code in my main project ?

I'm using XCode beta 5.
cheers